# Oracle Sql: Obtain a Sum of a Group, if Subgroup condition met

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dataset upon which I am trying to obain a summed value for each group, if a subgroup within each group meets a certain condition. I am not sure if this is possible, or if I am approaching this problem incorrectly.

My data is structured as following:

```
+----+-------------+---------+-------+
| ID | Transaction | Product | Value |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+
| 1  |      A      |    0    |   10  |
| 1  |      A      |    1    |   15  |
| 1  |      A      |    2    |   20  |
| 1  |      B      |    1    |   5   |
| 1  |      B      |    2    |   10  | 
+----+-------------+---------+-------+
```

In this example I want to obtain the sum of values by the `ID column`, if a transaction does not contain any products labeled 0. In the above described scenario, all values related to `Transaction A` would be excluded because `Product 0` was purchased. With the outcome being:

```
+----+-------------+
| ID | Sum of Value|
+----+-------------+
| 1  |      15     |  
+----+-------------+
```

This process would repeat for multiple `IDs` with each ID only containing the sum of values if the transaction does not contain product 0.

Comment: Your question is tagged with both oracle and tsql. Which are you using? TSQL is a proprietary Microsoft procedural language. Oracle is the database management system (DBMS) that uses the PL/SQL procedural language. Correct tagging will help us answer accurately.

Comment: Sorry about that, just Oracle. I must've mistakenly selected tsql instead of plsql

Comment: @VesperAnnstas Technically, Sybase (a non-MS product) also uses TSQL as Sybase and MSSQL share a history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . one method is to use `not exists` for the filtering:

```
select id, sum(value)
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.transaction = t.transaction and
                        t2.product = 0
                 )
group by id;
```

Comment: oh wow, thanks for the quick response. Let me try it out and get back to you.

Comment: This was perfect, worked as expected!! Thank you so much! Now I begin the process of understanding the query

Answer (score 1):

Do not need to use correlated subquery with not exists.
Just use group by.

```
with s (id, transaction, product, value) as (
select 1, 'A', 0, 10 from dual union all
select 1, 'A', 1, 15 from dual union all
select 1, 'A', 2, 20 from dual union all
select 1, 'B', 1, 5  from dual union all
select 1, 'B', 2, 10 from dual)
select id, sum(sum_value) as sum_value
from
   (select id, transaction,
    sum(value) as sum_value
    from s
    group by id, transaction
    having count(decode(product, 0, 1)) = 0
   )
group by id;

        ID  SUM_VALUE
---------- ----------
         1         15
```